# Setting ringtone to different sim cards Android

Tags: android, kotlin, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I am using `setActualDefaultRingtone` but it is only setting ringtone to sim one. Is there any way to set ringtone to sim 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't set ringtone for the second sim card as Android's API only support single sim
Manufacturers modify the OS according to their requirement.
So, it is not possible to set ringtone for second sim